# putting a hash value into an array in ruby

Tags: arrays, json, ruby, hash

I am trying to insert a list of account numbers into an array from an json return, I turned the json return into an hash, but I cannot for some reason insert the values into an array. I checked the hash locations on irb, and it gets the account number, for an example the location `my_hash["aws_accounts"][0]["owner_id"]`  will get me the first account number and `my_hash["aws_accounts"][0]["status"]["level"]`  will get me the status of the first account.

I essentially want to iterate through all the accounts and store the account number if its respective status color is "yellow".

HERE IS MY CODE:

```
 require 'json'
require 'rest-client'

 j = RestClient.get 'https://chapi.cloudhealthtech.com/v1/aws_accounts?api_key=###&page=1&per_page=100'
 my_hash = JSON.parse(j)
 accnt_size = my_hash["aws_accounts"].size
 intaccntsize = accnt_size.to_i
 account_number_array = Array.new

 x = 0
for accnt_iteration in x..intaccntsize do
     puts accnt_iteration
     if my_hash["aws_accounts"][accnt_iteration]["status"]["level"] == "yellow"
     account_number_array.push(my_hash["aws_accounts"][accnt_iteration]["owner_id"])
     end
end
```

HERE IS THE ERROR MESSAGE

```
in `block in <main>': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
from C:/Users/----/Desktop/-----/ruby_aws_sdk.rb:12:in `each'
from C:/Users/------/Desktop/-------/ruby_aws_sdk.rb:12:in `<main>'
```

any suggestions will help. thanks.

Comment: This question could be improved with an example. Give both a simplified hash (with no reference to the JSON string) and array, and show your desired result (as a valid Ruby object). It's helpful to assign a variable to each input (e.g, `arr = [1,2,3...]`, `h = { ...}`). That way readers can refer to the variables without having define them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual solution to your problem is to use the 3 dot range instead of 2 dot (3 dots is end-exclusive and 2 dots is end-inclusive) as seen in the following (this uses the same `my_hash` as my second code block below):

```
for x in 0..my_hash["aws_accounts"].size do
  puts x
end
# 0
# 1
# 2
=> 0..2
my_hash["aws_accounts"][2]
=> nil
for x in 0...my_hash["aws_accounts"].size do
  puts x
end
# 0
# 1
=> 0...2
my_hash["aws_accounts"][1]
=> {"owner_id"=>2, "status"=>{"level"=>"orange"}}
```

Instead of getting the number of accounts and trying to access them through their index, I would just iterate over the accounts on their own. Here's a quick sample, with what I believe (based on your description) are the relevant pieces of `my_hash` and your expected output.

```
my_hash = {
  "aws_accounts" => [
    { "owner_id" => 1, "status" => { "level" => "yellow" } },
    { "owner_id" => 2, "status" => { "level" => "orange" } }
  ]
}

account_number_array = []

my_hash["aws_accounts"].each do |account|
  if account["status"]["level"] == "yellow"
    account_number_array << account["owner_id"]
  end
end

puts account_number_array.inspect
# => [1]
```